# State-of-the-art geometry book?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, geometry, textbook-recommendation, books

For my best friend's birthday, I am looking for a geometry book. He's currently doing his math PhD and is really fond of geometry, especially hyperbolic or higher-dimensional ones, also interested in (star or not) polytopes. He is no beginner at all, having read Coxeter or Gromov, so I am looking for a real hard-math book for him.

I looked at Thurston, but it seems most of his works are actually freely available online, and I would prefer not to give him a free-printed pdf as a present :/

It may be a theorem or theory-presentation book, maybe with a historical part though not necessary nor prioritary.

What would you advice to me ?

Comment: If I were a geometer, I would want to pick out any "state-of-the-art" book myself. For a present I would much rather receive something historically significant, like [a copy of Riemann's Habilitation Lecture](https://books.google.com/books?id=l5oFDAAAQBAJ) for example.

Comment: Also, there's a high probability that your friend owns a state of the art book that fits within his interests. You could of course ask him if there's a book he wishes he had but seems to be too expensive.

Comment: Maybe buy him some hyperbolic or higher-dimensional sculpture instead? Like ones here https://www.shapeways.com/shops/henryseg

Comment: @ZenoRogue: wow! Thanks for pointing that out. There are some really awesome stuff there.

Comment: A state-of-the-art book about *all* of geometry?? That is going to be taugh...

Answer (score 6):

1. M. Berger, A Panoramic view of Riemannian geometry,
2. M. Berger, Geometry revealed. A Jacob's Ladder to modern higher geometry.

I promise you that your friend will enjoy this gift if s/he likes geometry, and does not have these books yet.